# jqBootstrapValidation form submitting even if not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im using jqBootstrapValidation to validate a form and all works well except for the password.

For example if I try to submit the form without filling in the fields it wont let me nor will it let me submit the form if email isn't in form example@site.com but even though I added data-validation-match-match tag to my second password input, the form still submit if the passwords don't match.

my code is:

```
<?php
$error = "";
include ('dblink.php');
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['s_logged_n'])){
header("Location: index.php");
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
if($_POST['form'] === 'login') 
    {
    $username = mysqli_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['user']));
    $password = md5(trim($_POST['password']));

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // now we check if they are activated

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {

        if($row['Activated'] > 0)
        {

            $_SESSION['s_logged_n'] = 'true';
            $_SESSION['s_username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['s_name'] = $row['Name'];

            header("Location: index.php");

        }else
        {
            $error = "<Br><div class=\"alert alert-warning\">Your account hasnt yet been activated.</div>";
        }


    }
    else
        {
        $error = "<Br><div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Your username/password do not match.</div>";
        }
}
if($_POST['form'] === 'register') 
    {
        $first = addslashes(trim($_POST['fname']));
        $surname = addslashes(trim($_POST['lname']));
        $abr = mb_substr($surname, 0, 3);
        $username = $first . $abr;
        $email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
        $poste = addslashes(trim($_POST['poste']));
        $pass = addslashes(trim($_POST['pass']));
        $salary = addslashes(trim($_POST['salary']));
        $conf = addslashes(trim($_POST['cpass']));
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $date = date("d, m y");
        $password = md5($pass);
    }
}
?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
</script>
<body >
<div style="background-color:#CC0000; height: 100%" >
</br>
</br>
</br>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default" >
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="page-header">
  <h1>Login</small></h1>
</div>


  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</span>
  <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div></br>

 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
</span>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
 <?php echo $error;?> 

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="login" />
      <button type="submit" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>




 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your first name." required>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="id="lname"" placeholder="Your last name." required>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email." required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="poste" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Poste</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <select class="form-control" id="poste" name="poste">
        <option value="Surface de Vente">Surface de Vente</option>
        <option value="Caisse">Caisse</option>
        <option value="Protection des biens">Protection des biens</option>
        <option value="Circulation des marchandises">Circulation des marchandises</option>
        <option value="Préposé à la marque">Préposé à la marque</option>
        <option value="Réserve">Réserve</option>
        <option value="Électronique">Électronique</option>
        <option value="Biens Modes">Biens Modes</option>
        <option value="Starbucks">Starbucks</option>
        <option value="Ressources humaines">Ressources humaines</option>
     </select> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="salary" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Salary</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Your salary." required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label >
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" minlength="6" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" required>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cpass" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" minlength="6" class="form-control" id="cpass" name="cpass" data-validation-match-match="pass" required>
    </div>
  </div>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="form" value="register" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Register <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

the form, which is in there is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your first name." required>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="id="lname"" placeholder="Your last name." required>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email." required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="poste" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Poste</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <select class="form-control" id="poste" name="poste">
        <option value="Surface de Vente">Surface de Vente</option>
        <option value="Caisse">Caisse</option>
        <option value="Protection des biens">Protection des biens</option>
        <option value="Circulation des marchandises">Circulation des marchandises</option>
        <option value="Préposé à la marque">Préposé à la marque</option>
        <option value="Réserve">Réserve</option>
        <option value="Électronique">Électronique</option>
        <option value="Biens Modes">Biens Modes</option>
        <option value="Starbucks">Starbucks</option>
        <option value="Ressources humaines">Ressources humaines</option>
     </select> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="salary" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Salary</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Your salary." required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label >
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" minlength="6" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" required>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cpass" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" minlength="6" class="form-control" id="cpass" name="cpass" data-validation-match-match="pass" required>
    </div>
  </div>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="form" value="register" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Register <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
        </form>
```

and the javascript is:

```
<script>
  $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
</script>
```

I get no error in my js console and I dont see what the error could be, anyone is familiar with this?

Also its ignoring the min character.

Comment: Although I appreciate the paste of all your code, you need to put the relevant code directly into your question.  Since the issue is with the password, just show the HTML for the form itself + the password fields, along with the Javascript that calls the validation.  The main reason we ask this, is that if the `paste.ee` site dies, your question becomes useless unless the code is here!

Comment: Im not able to post my code here without it looking really weird :S

Comment: After you paste it in, select it all and then click the "code" button at the top of the editing window (it looks like {}).  That will indent it and then it will flow better.

Comment: I changed it hope it helps.